Name of movie that had brother sister subhuman special agents
This was maybe 20yrs ago. Action sci fi movie. There was one sequel to the first movie. Two organizations had special agents called 'subs'. They were humans combined with animal genetics. The sister was the good agent. I think her character was named Cat or Kat? Actress was dark haired, perhaps Hispanic decent, age approximately 30's. The brother was the bad agent. I think his character was named Cain or Kane. The actor was dark haired, perhaps Italian or Hispanic decent, age approximately 30's. Fight scenes were hand to hand combat, rather than weapons for the most part. I thought the story line was pretty good and it was not a bad movie for it's time. I would like to find it again. Thanks in advance for any guesses.

"Cyborg 2", (1993), had a character nicknamed "Cash" played by dark-haired Angelina Jolie.  Could that be what you're thinking of?  http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0106639/

How does the animal genetics part come into picture? Do the characters have animalistic moves, fluffy ears even?

It's not close enough to your description but try the TV Series Dark Angel with Jessica Alba it matches some of what you described but it's not close enough to list as an answer.

repfarm, if you're still around, I may have a lead. I stumbled across this and remembered your question: In 1992, George R. R. Martin pitched a sci-fi pilot to ABC called Doorways. It was not picked up but aired as a movie. It was about Cat, a fugitive from a parallel Earth, pursued by the evil 'manhound' Thane after landing in our world. The dark-haired Cat, played by Anne Le Guernec, is described as 'feral':

Dark-haired Thane, played by Robert Knepper, is described by Martin as 'part human, part animal, part cybernetic':

The plot revolved around travelling to parallel worlds through doors a-la Sliders (in fact, Wiki suggests that Sliders may have ripped it off), and according to a couple of reviews I found, it was fairly decent.
Does it ring any bells?

Robert Knepper: great actor, brings nostalgic Prison Break memories.

Cyborg 2, (1993), had a character nicknamed "Cash" played by dark-haired Angelina Jolie. Could that be what you're thinking of?  It had the two organizations:

In the year 2074, the cybernetics market is dominated by two rival
  companies: USA's Pinwheel Robotics and Japan's Kobayashi Electronics.


OK, I found it for real this time. ;) Ironically you are looking for a 'Dark Angel', just not the actual show. This is Chameleon 3: Dark Angel from 2000, the second sequel to the TV film Chameleon from 1998. From a review of the original film:

A young woman [called Kam], a laboratory genetic creation (a "sub" in this movie) [...] has been programmed as the perfect Federal agent, naturally with some enhanced abilities, and a total incapacity to feel emotion. 

And in Chameleon 3:

Bobbie Phillips returns as Agent Kam in this tele-film. [...] Also in this movie is Kane, Kam's brother who [battles her and] has the skills of Wolf, Lizard and Bat.

Here's a clip (a leather compilation dubbed in Russian... sorry, it's the only one I could find):



